# How to give multiple arguments in tensorflow Model call function?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a model in tensorflow by extending the 'Model' class in tensorflow.keras. I need to pass two arguments in the 'call' function of this class, input images x (224,224,3) and output label y. But I get the following error while building the model:

> ValueError: Currently, you cannot build your model if it has
>   positional or keyword arguments that are not input to the model, but
>   are required for its 'call' method.

```
class myCNN(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(myCNN, self).__init__()

    base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3), weights='imagenet')
    layer_name = 'block5_conv3'
    self.conv_1 = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
    self.flatten = L.Flatten(name='flatten')
    self.fc1 = L.Dense(1000, activation='relu', name='fc1')
    self.final = L.Activation('softmax')

  # The problem is because I need y
  def call(self, x, y):
    x = self.conv_1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    return self.final(x)

model = myCNN()
model.build((None, 224, 224, 3, 1))
```

Comment: Why do you need y? You are not using it in the current computation inside call

Comment: I have not shown the usage. I need to mask x before passing it to flatten layer. The mask is dependant on y. As of now I did a workaround by passing [x,y] as a single argument to call()

Comment: That's not a workaround, it is how it should be implemented.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Inputs parameter of call method can be an `input tensor` or `list/tuple of input tensors`.

You can pass two arguments like this:

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    x = inputs[0]
    y = inputs[1]
    x = self.conv_1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    return self.final(x)
```